# Show total cpu for a set of processes in linux

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, top, htop

I want to monitor the total cpu usage of all the process corresponding to some filter. For example all the process witch corresponds to some executable.

On top or htop I can filter the process list, but I cannot show the total amount of cpu usage for the resulting list of process.

I want to know if is there a way of doing that with top or htop, or which terminal or gui tool can I use for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
pidstat -t 10 -p PID1, Pid2
```

will give you the CPU for those PIDs.

Comment: than you! Is there a limit for the number of PIDs? like in top?

Comment: it supports the option "ALL" which means all running processes on the system. Therefore i think as long as you have a decent length of PIDs to manage, it should be okay.

Comment: This is not a standard tool installed like grep etc. Mostly it comes with sysstat package.